# I am receiving a Fatal Error for calling a member function close() on an non-object

Tags: php, mysql

This is a script that updates a field value in a table. After querying I am getting the error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function close() on a non-object

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors','On');

    define('DB_HOST', 'xxxxxx');
    define('DB_NAME', 'xxxxxx');
    define('DB_USER','xxxxxx');
    define('DB_PASSWORD','xxxxxxx');

    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_error());

     if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }

    $result = $mysqli->query("update people_table set FirstName = 'Jon' where LastName = 'Smith'") or die($mysqli->error);
    $result->close();

    ?>
```

$result is an object to my view which confuses me

Comment: why are you closing the result set? it's supposed to be the connection: [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php)

Comment: Because I need to free it to use it again (I am making multiple queries in the same script)

Comment: if you want to free up the result set then use [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php)

Answer (score 1):

i think this is what you need to write rather than the result object

```
$mysqli->close();
```